# Simple cookie bar - close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I'm trying to make simple cookie bar.

Here's my code.

```css
#cookie-bar-bottom {
 bottom: 0;
}
.cookie-bar {
 width: 100%;
 line-height: 30px;
 left: 0;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 100;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.70);
}
.cookie-content {
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
.cookie-hide {
 margin-left: 80px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 border: 1px solid white;
 outline: none;
}
.cookie-hide:hover {
 background-color: #155670;
}
```

```html
<div id="cookie-bar-bottom" class="cookie-bar">
   <div class="cookie-content">
     <p>
         We use cookies to enhance your experience in our web site. By visiting it, you agree our <a href="#" class="cookie-policy">Cookies Policy</a>.
            <input id="cookie-hide" class="cookie-hide" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none'" value="I understand" type="button">
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It closes when I hit 'I understand' button. The problem is with that close button because when I refresh my website cookie bar appears again. I wouldn't like to see it when I'm refreshing my website.

I don't want to use any PHP function btw. it should be - I think, java/jQuery script/function, and should work with my structure of cookie bar code.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is with that close button because when I refresh my website cookie bar appears again. I wouldn't like to see it when I'm refreshing my website.

This happens because you do not create the corresponding cookie and test on document ready if the cookie already exist.

From [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie) you can write something like:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
       if (getCookie('ItsAllOk').length > 0) {
         document.getElementById('cookie-bar-bottom').style.display = 'none';
       }
        document.getElementById('cookie-hide').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            createCookie('ItsAllOk', true, 1);
        })
});
```

The snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  if (getCookie('ItsAllOk').length > 0) {
    document.getElementById('cookie-bar-bottom').style.display = 'none';
  }
  document.getElementById('cookie-hide').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    createCookie('ItsAllOk', true, 1);
  })
});



var createCookie = function(name, value, days) {
  var expires;
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  }
  else {
    expires = "";
  }
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
  if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    if (c_start != -1) {
      c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
      c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
      if (c_end == -1) {
        c_end = document.cookie.length;
      }
      return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

```css
#cookie-bar-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}
.cookie-bar {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 30px;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.70);
}
.cookie-content {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.cookie-hide {
  margin-left: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  outline: none;
}
.cookie-hide:hover {
  background-color: #155670;
}
```

```html
<div id="cookie-bar-bottom" class="cookie-bar">
    <div class="cookie-content">
        <p>
            We use cookies to enhance your experience in our web site. By visiting it, you agree our <a href="#" class="cookie-policy">Cookies Policy</a>.
            <input id="cookie-hide" class="cookie-hide" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none'" value="I understand" type="button">
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage` to store an item when someone accepts, and only show the cookie bar if that item doesn't exist.

```js
if (!localStorage.getItem('cookie')) {
  $('#cookie-bar-bottom').show();
}

$('#cookie-hide').on('click',function() {
  localStorage.setItem('cookie',true);
  $('#cookie-bar-bottom').hide();
})
```

```css
#cookie-bar-bottom {
 bottom: 0;
  display: none;
}
.cookie-bar {
 width: 100%;
 line-height: 30px;
 left: 0;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 100;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.70);
}
.cookie-content {
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
.cookie-hide {
 margin-left: 80px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 border: 1px solid white;
 outline: none;
}
.cookie-hide:hover {
 background-color: #155670;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cookie-bar-bottom" class="cookie-bar">
   <div class="cookie-content">
     <p>
         We use cookies to enhance your experience in our web site. By visiting it, you agree our <a href="#" class="cookie-policy">Cookies Policy</a>.
            <input id="cookie-hide" class="cookie-hide" value="I understand" type="button">
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you want to achieve is simple. But some more JavaScript is needed.

The code easy implement (just copy/paste) is there: https://cookienotice.js.org

**Edit:** full solution

**Styles:** Add the following code to your HTML `<head></head>` section.

```
<style>
#cookie-notice {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    max-width: 450px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #555;
}
.cookie-notice-more {
    margin: 0 0.25rem;
    text-decoration-style: dashed;
    color: inherit;
}
.cookie-notice-close {
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 0.125rem;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #888;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #cookie-notice {
        bottom: 1rem;
        border-radius: 0.25rem;
    }
    .cookie-notice-close {
        float: right;
    }
}
</style>
```

**Notice block:** Add the following code to your HTML `<body></body>` section.

```
<div id="cookie-notice">
    We use cookies to deliver better experience.
    <a href="https://cookienotice.js.org/about-cookies" class="cookie-notice-more" target="_blank" rel="noopener">More info...</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="cookie-notice-close" onclick="closeCookieNotice()">OK</a>
</div>
```

**Script:** Add the following code to your HTML footer before the `</body>` closing tag.

```
<script>
function closeCookieNotice() {
    const nowDate = new Date();
    const expireDate = new Date(nowDate.setDate(nowDate.getDate() + 30)).toUTCString();
    document.cookie = "cookie_notice=0;path=/;expires=" + expireDate + ";";
    document.getElementById("cookie-notice").style.display = "none";
};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const cookie_notice = ('; ' + document.cookie).split('; cookie_notice=').pop().split(';')[0];
    if (cookie_notice !== "0") {
        document.getElementById("cookie-notice").style.display = "block";
    }
});
</script>
```

I've participated in developing some themes for cookie notice.

You can give it another look using [themes](https://cookienotice.js.org/themes).